# Groovy slacksend function doesn't work in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy slacksend function to notify to slack channels.

```
 slackSend(
                        channel: "#channel-name",
                        color: "warning",
                        message: "Could not confirm server started - ${env.BRANCH} (<${env.BUILD_URL}/console|Details> - <${SERVER_URL}|Open>)"


                    )
```

But the output is something like this

```
 [Pipeline] slackSend
 run slackstepsend, step null:false, desc :true
 Slack Send Pipeline step configured values from global config - baseUrl: 
 true, teamDomain: true, token: true, channel: false, color: false
```

and there is not notification being sent. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Those values in your pipeline output should be getting populated with the values from your jenkinsfile. eg, `teamDomain: true` should be `teamDomain: <your_slack_team>`. You can pass each of these as a parameter in the slacksend invocation in your Jenkinsfile just as you are with channel, color, and message. Also, your channel name doesn't require `#`, though i don't know if that would cause it to fail.

Comment: `teamDomain` is an argument of `slackSend()`?  I've never heard of that.  What is the full list of arguments for `slackSend()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
slackSend channel: '#yourchannelname', color: color, message: 'Starting branch', teamDomain: 'your_enterprise_team_domain', token: 'token_generated_from_jenkins_slack_integration'
```

[image: see image for token details]